# Bluetooth on Probook with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, bluetooth

I have a ProBook 6570b with Windows 8.1 from HP. I can't find any bluetooth settings. Is it possible that the computer doesn't have bluetooth at all? Can it be installed? Do I have to implement something in the hardware?

I've installed "Broadcom Bluetooth Software (American, International)" from http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5212930&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4158

When I'm clicking "Launch Bluetooth settings" in Windows 8.1, I get directed to Airplane Mode under PC Settings. In "Wiresless devices" only Wi-Fi is listed.

Answer (score -1):

If your pc doesn't have the integrated bluetooth, you can buy an external one I use one of them. It simply works like a usb pendrive.

Comment: This fails to address the problem presented in the question.

Comment: Would it be realistic that such "new" computer doesn't have bluetooth integrated?

Comment: @Jamgreen it is realistic to not make the assumption a new computer has bluetooth